# INotifyPropertyChanged not called correctly with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-core, inotifypropertychanged

I have a very simple entity which is used (as part of a view model) to display UI in my MVVM UWP app. I am using lazy loading proxies over a SQLite database.

The entity has two properties - Name and ID. Both are correctly raising the `PropertyChanged` event.

I am trying to implement a rename method, which presents UI to rename the entity. This works correctly and the database is updated, however the UI binding does not update.

I bound to the `PropertyChanged` event to try and see what was happening and I've noticed some odd behaviour. When the name is changed, the sender is the proxy and the proxy has the previous name. If I change the name again I see the first rename as the `Name` property.

If I remove Entity Framework from the equation and populate the UI with the same entity types, the app works as I would expect. For some reason `PropertyChanged` is being raised by EF before the proxy value has been updated.

I have tried using [ChangeTrackingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetrackingstrategy?view=efcore-2.1) with no effect (like this):

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasChangeTrackingStrategy(ChangeTrackingStrategy.ChangedNotifications);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include sample repro. I don't think EF Core is raising (can it?) `PropertyChanged` event, that's the responsibility of the class implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, i.e. your entity class (even though it's subclassed by a proxy). `ChangeTrackingStrategy` has nothing to do with that - it controls EF Core change tracking info/state, not the entity property values. Anyway, sample entity class implementation would help figuring out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'll try and get something up on GitHub shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling across issues with bindings using Entity Framework with observable objects, my underlying issue was that the `SetProperty` method, which all properties call to update, was marked virtual in my base object.

The effect was that the EF proxy was overriding this, which caused weird things to happen - the UI not updating, typing in text boxes and characters at the end moving to the start, etc.

Note that EF uses DynamicProxy under the covers, which will proxy all virtual methods.